# R: Highlighting specific values in CSV-table

Tags: r, csv, colors

I would like to write a CSV file in R. For example this:

```
name <- c("a", "a", "b", "b")
class <- c("c1", "c1", "c3", "c3")
year <- c("2010", "2010", "2008", "2008")
value <- c(100, 33, 100, 90)
valueMessage <-c("meh2", "meh", NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(name, class, year, value, valueMessage)
df 

write.csv2(df,file ="df.csv")
```

I would like to write this data to a csv-file but I would like to highlight some cells or whole rows with a certain colour. Imagine that I want to highlight all the rows where value==100 so the file should look normal, but the two lines have red cells.

Is there any way to do something like that?

Comment: The short answer is no.  The long answer is also no.  Csv is a text data format, not a display format.

Answer (score 1):

Plain CSV alone: no. "Something like that": yes.

If you are stuck to CSV, try saving a list of the cells to highlight/remember in an auxilary file for further elaboration?

Otherwise you could use another format, even xls with its advantages and disadvantages. See http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/ for an extensive discusion of ways to cope with xls files, including pros and cons. Using **package xlsx**, "the user has control to set colors, fonts, data formats, add borders, hide/unhide sheets, add/remove rows, add/remove sheets, etc" (see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html).

Comment: It does not have to be CSV alone, "something like that" is totally fine. I tried to install the xlsx package but I saw I need Java for that. I can't install Java because of, well, reasons. Is there another format you could recommend? Before I opened this thread, I was working with hwriter and HTML-files but that's not really what I want.

Comment: Do you need the data to be read again by a computer later, or just need a nice human-readable version? In the latter case, might sweave or knitr be an option?

Comment: Only human-readable, but does not have to be nice (like, does not have to ouput something that's report-worthy). I only want to return some of the data (only where value > 30 for example) and I want to highlight specific rows (where value==100 for example). What I don't want is having to process or include the code somewhere else (I've looked into sweave before, but as far as I saw, you have to include it into TeX?). I would simply like to output a table where some values are highlighted.

Comment: Might it be a workaround to a) filter your results and print only those that meet your criteria or sort them according to value (e.g. df[df$value==100], or ?sort / ?order, respectively), or b) introduce a column df$value.flag <- ifelse(df$value == 100, "\*", "") and sort your columns df <- df[, c("name", "class", "year", "value", "value.flag", "valueMessage")], so that each value meeting your criteria is flagged by a "\*"?

Comment: The thing is I also have different criteria. Highlighting value==100 with red, value <100 yellow, value==0 green, something like that. And simply having a "*" or "!" or whatever in the table is not as clear as I would like to have it. At the moment I'm trying to work with shiny. It's on the way of doing what I want, so I guess I'll stick with HTML. Thanks for your help!